# Next.js is not recognizing '@types/react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

When I try to run my Next.js app with `npm run dev` I get an error message saying that I don't have the required packages to run Next with Typescript:

```
Please install @types/react by running:

        npm install --save-dev @types/react

If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
```

However, the module '@types/react' is installed. I tried running `npm install --save-dev @types/react` and got no error messages (just a bunch of warnings but I don't think they are the problem).

How can I solve this and run the project?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in the current @types/react version (specifically v18.0.2), you can downgrade to 18.0.1 with `npm install --save-dev @types/react@18.0.1`

Source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36085

Comment: For yarn:
yarn add --dev @types/react@18.0.1

Comment: I would add that you should look for a `@types/react` version that matches with the React version of your project. On my case, is a **React 16** project and I used `16.9.49` instead, having my problem solved. Thanks

Comment: I solved with @lgargantini answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the same way, but I couldn't resolve this yet.

Comment: having the same issue with no luck

Comment: @DasunTharanga and @ Nikster have you tried seeing if any new TypeScript issues were opened that could be related to your problem? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue++is%3Aopen+typescript

Answer (score 21):

I used `yarn add -D @types/react@18.0.1` and it worked perfectly!
Netsu is right, seems like there is a bug in the current @types/react version (specifically v18.0.2).

Answer (score 2):

Note that Next 11 has a slightly dodgy check for the existence of @types/react.  The later package has simply chosen to express its exports in a different but valid way (which fails the check).  After a slightly annoying manual binary-search I can say the latest version of @types/react for React 17 which Next 11 can accept is 17.0.46

The same check may still be in place for later versions of Next, which would explain why people are reporting they can use @types/react 18.0.1 with it but not 18.0.2.

(at the time of writing the latest versions of Next 11 and React 17 are next@11.1.4 and @types/react@17.0.46, so this situation could change, but both are probably considered legacy at this point, so it might not.  I'm only using Next 11 and React 17 as stepping stones in an upgrade to current versions)

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you versions of @types/react, react, and react-dom are locked and aligned in package.json

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 3508c106..cbc412d0 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -47,9 +47,9 @@

-    "react": "^17.0.2",
+    "react": "17.0.2",
-    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
+    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
-    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
+    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
```

Consider disabling optimistic updates for build stability. If you are using the CLI you may require usage of the save-exact command

```
npm install --save-exact 'react@17.0.2' // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add --only to production:

RUN yarn install --only=production

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach i took here was to create a new nextjs project using `npx create-next-app`. And then copied the versions of all the dependencies and devDependencies.

Here is a sample `package.json`. I got this after create new nextjs project.

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.1",
    "@types/react": "18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Copy all the versions listed in the package.json you get after create new nextjs project. This will ensure that your core dependencies are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I was also hitting this error.  Turns out I didn't have yarn installed which prevented the library from being auto installed when I tried to run applications using the command:

```
npm run dev
```

To correct the problem install yarn using the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Then retry to the start command for the app:

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue when starting an old project, I solution was to use older version of node modules,
installing node module with version 14.21.3 LTS worked for me.