# Vercel not recognizing typescript or @types/react when deploying Next.js Project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js, vercel

All of a sudden, my Next.js deployment to Vercel stopped working after the latest deploy and started complaining about not having @types/react AND typescript installed.

```
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.
Please install typescript and @types/react by running:

    npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react

If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
```

In my project I am using:

```
  "@types/react": "18.2.15",
  "typescript": "5.1.6"
```

I did not modify these packages at all in the failed deployment. The only change I made to the dependencies was adding cheerio. I tried rebuilding the package.json as well and that did not get rid of this error.

I came across this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843307/next-js-is-not-recognizing-types-react) with almost the same issue. However since it is outdated I decided to open a new question for 2023. The old solution was downgrading the @types/react version but it does not work for me.

How can I get past this blocker?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was setting the NODE_ENV secret in production. After removing it, my issues were gone. I did not know Next JS will automatically set this secret when building.

Seems like it should not throw an error if the user accidentally sets it like I did. Or at least throw a helpful error. But nonetheless, my solution was to remove the NODE_ENV secret from the Vercel environment variables.